# Software updater needs more disk space

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage

I got the following error message from Software Updater:

```
The upgrade needs a total of 74,6 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 68,3 M of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

How can I get more disc space? I have

```
df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root  454G   13G  418G   3% /
none                          4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         384M  1,3M  383M   1% /run
none                          5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                          1,9G   24M  1,9G   2% /run/shm
none                          100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2                     237M  219M  6,1M  98% /boot
/dev/sda1                     511M  3,4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

Comment: The suggestions in the notice are not enough?

Comment: @Alvar I read but somehow I thought it is enough to empty the trash on the desktop. Well, by emptying the boot directory helped.

Comment: run the command suggested `sudo apt-get clean` and delete old kernels. Make sure you keep the one you are using and I suggest you keep the previous one but delete all others as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/2793/107450)

Comment: You have a seperate partition for /boot, so it only has a certain ammount of space (273MB). Everytime there is a new kernel, and you update to it it creates a file in /boot, over time and by not removing old kernels this will fill up. run "sudo apt-get autoremove" then "sudo apt-get autoclean" and it will probably be okay.

Comment: Hmmm, dont see how this is marked duplicate. The issues are related, but I think there is a better answer for this particular question (at least it was for me). Like @robblue2x suggested, in terminal: 
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
This solved the issue for me. I guess this will be true for many others that encounter this error.

Comment: @Alvar to be fair, the software uploader dialog msg does suggest that the action required is to empty the trash folder and run sudo apt-get clean - neither of which solve the problem. I can also add that the idea of deleting kernel related files from the /boot partition is slightly intimidating - hence the OP is a good one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced this same message with Ubuntu 14.04. The answer to this question took care of the problem by removing old Linux kernels from /boot. It freed almost a half gig of space there.

Here's the link:
[How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)